# How to use .htaccess to display .webp images ONLY when the .webp file exists?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webp

I'm trying to display webp files on my website to make it load faster. I'm using .htaccess to rewrite all images to end with .wepb and everything works like a charm. sadly I'm not the only developer on the website and we also have a blog where people add pictures.

The problem is that every new image that does not have a copy of that image in a webp format is not showing as a jpg or anything else, it's just broken.

I researched the web to find multiple scripts to try but none are working as I would want it too. It might not be possible to do this only in htaccess.

I think what is happening is my script is looking if the browser supports webp and **if the file exists but once the condition is true for one image it skips the rewriteCond for every other request**.

How do we make this persistent?

I'm using Laravel framework so maybe I could solve this problem with php.

Apache 2.4.37
php 7.1.26
(running on wamp server for testing)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 # Does browser explicitly support webp?
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome [OR]

 # OR Is request from Page Speed
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Google Page Speed Insights" [OR]

 # OR does this browser explicitly support webp
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp [OR]

 # AND does a webp image exists?
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.webp -f

 # THEN send the webp image and set the env var webp
 RewriteRule (.+\.(?:jpe?g|png))$ $1.webp [NC,L]

</IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_mime.c>
   AddType image/webp .webp
 </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP} off

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    ## LEVERAGE BROWSER CACHING ##
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 week"
## LEVERAGE BROWSER CACHING ##

    AddType image/svg+xml svg
    AddType image/svg+xml svgz

</IfModule>
```

The code says: check if chrome or speed insight or browser support AND
check if the file imgexemple.jpg.webp exist then display *.jpg.webp instead or just .jpg

IT works! But when people add new img to my website that don't have thatimg.jpg.webp it will not show the plain thatimg.jpg it will try to show thatimg.jpg.webp which doesnt exist.

**How do I tell it to run the if statement for EVERY image on the page?**